# Inconsistent floating point substraction

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy

in Javascript:

This expression (2.0 - 1.1) returns 0.8999999999999999.

However this one (4.0 - 1.1) return 2.9.

Can anybody explain this inconsistency?

I understand that 1.1 can't be represented in floating point.

Answer (score 4):

The "inconsistency" has nothing to do with floating-point subtraction, and is instead a consequence of how Javascript displays numbers (it's also completely consistent).

As you say, `1.1` isn't representable, so it's value isn't actually 1.1.  Instead it has the value:

```
1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
```

Subtracting this value from `2.0` is exact, and the result is:

```
0.899999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
```

This number is not the closest representable number to `0.9` (that would be `0.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625`), so if it printed as `0.9`, the value would not survive a round trip to decimal and back (being able to round-trip numbers to their decimal representation and back is a highly desirable property).  Thus, it is instead printed with sufficient precision to specify the correct value:

```
0.8999999999999999
```

In your second example, we subtract from `4.0` and get:

```
2.899999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
```

which *is* the closest representable number to `2.9` (the next closest number is `2.9000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625`), so it can be printed as just `2.9` and still have the value survive a round-trip.